# SPARK AR why my material turn black once I try my filter on mobile?

Tags: facebook, scripting, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

When i try to plug a texture in my material via Scripting(js)I obtain two different results:
-Inside Spark AR: I can see my plane with the texture on it;
-On mobile: I can see my plane, but it is totally black. If i don't plug the texture I can see it shaded with the right color.
Why this happens? I really don't understand where is the issue.
Thank you guys
[image]

I expected to see the plane with the texture applied on It